# How can I fix muffled sound on my Samsung Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, audio, microphone

I recently purchased a i9000 and the voice quality over the microphone is horrible. The sound is muffled. Person on the other side of the line cannot make out what I'm saying. Is there a fix?

Answer (score 1):

1. Pop off the back cover and make sure there's not a sticker or anything over the speaker or mic.
2. You could try Voodoo Sound.  It's a custom kernel for SGS devices but if you don't want to mess around with that you could just try [the Voodoo Control app](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.controlappdonate), it can do some improvements without the kernel.  (If you do use the kernel you really need the app as well.)
3. Otherwise, I would assume it's a hardware problem and you should get a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this week. Did the switching off of noise reduction and finally rebooted completely but still same problem. In desperation I stuck a pin in the tiny mic hole at the bottom of the phone and waggled it about... Hey presto! All sorted!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was reading all of these posts about clearing cache, system resets, etc, etc. Then I read your post. Sure enough, there was some gunk over the speaker hole. Cleaned it off and everything was fine.

My husband's S3 keep restarting and wouldn't boot. I took it to two different people and both of them said, hardware failure - you need to replace it.

Since I had pretty much nothing to lose that that point, I took the back off, got into the area where the button was, worked it back and forth a few times, cleaned the case around the button, put it back together and the thing booted up perfectly. That was over a year ago and it hasn't given him a problem since.

Comment: I suppose you wanted to address [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/4840/96277) but couldn't post a comment.

Comment: Seems fine, this is a bit chatty but explains what the root issue could be rather than one specific solution.